# Django shared template

Tags: django, templates, sharing

I'm looking how to do the best something like a UserControl in ASP.NET in Django.

For example:
1) There's a Book model defined
2) There's a regular representation of the book which I want to use all over my site (called "book_template.html").

Now let's say I want to use this one representation from 2 views: recent_books_view, popular_books_view. It can be done directly like

```
from django import template
```

t = template.Template('My name is {{ name }}.')
book1_context = template.Context({'book': Book1})
book2_context = template.Context({'book': Book2})
book3_context = template.Context({'book': Book3})
...

render_to_response('recent_books.html', 
   {'content': t.render(book1_context) + t.render(book2_context) + t.render(book3_context)})

render_to_response('popular_books.html', 
   {'content': t.render(book4_context) + t.render(book5_context) + t.render(book6_context)})

But I'm sure there's a better way...

For example, in ASP.NET you can say in template file "apply for array 'Books' this shared template", and then in the backend you just specify variable 'Books'. Is that possible in Django?

Answer (score 3):

In your python code:

```
context['books'] = blah blah # Make a list of books somehow.
return render_to_response('popular_books.html', context)
```

In popular_books.html:

```
<p>Look, books:</p>
{% for book in books %}
    {% include "book.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, in book.html:

```
<p>I am a book, my name is {{book.name}}</p>
```

There are more interesting ways to modularize, such as creating a custom tag, so that you could, for example:

```
<p>Look, books:</p>
{% for b in books %}
    {% book b %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is what you want to do. You probably want some Book.objects.filter(...) to select your popular books and your recent books.

Comment: This is a good way to do it. I pass lists of objects to my templates all the time. So often, in fact, that I have a template "list.html" that most of my other templates inherit from. (list.html has common elements like pagination control.)

Comment: That's nice! How can I define {% book b %} template?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this tutorial [Chapter 4 of the Django book: The Django Template System](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter04).

See block tags and template inheritance.